# Publish Media item as soon as uploaded

Tags: media-library, publishing

I want to publish the Media item as soon as it is uploaded in the Media library. I was looking at different pipelines to resolve this but couldn't figure out which one is the ideal one to do so.

As it is a media item item saved event is not triggered.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with `uiUpload` processor:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <processors>
            <uiUpload>
                <processor mode="on" type="{YourSolutionName.ProjectName.PublishMediaItem}, AssemblyNameSpace{YourSolutionName.ProjectName}" patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.Upload.Done, Sitecore.Kernel']" />
            </uiUpload>
        </processors>
</configuration>
```

Your class will be:

```
namespace YourSolutionName.ProjectName
{
    public class PublishMediaItem: UploadProcessor
    {
        public void Process(UploadArgs args)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");

            foreach (string index in args.Files)
            {
                HttpPostedFile file = args.Files[index];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName))
                {
                    //write your publish code here
                    args.AbortPipeline();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add your custom processor into the pipeline or replace the existing processor with a custom one. you can change the standard Sitecore behavior in order to enhance or change the way they work.

The file uploading process is defined by pipeline `<uiUpload>` in the `web.config` file. Please have a look at the  `<processors>` section in this file:

```
 <uiUpload>

      <processor mode="on" type="Sitecore.Pipelines.Upload.ResolveFolder, Sitecore.Kernel" />

      <processor mode="on" type="Sitecore.Pipelines.Upload.Save, Sitecore.Kernel" />

      <processor mode="on" type="Sitecore.Pipelines.Upload.Unzip, Sitecore.Kernel" />

      <processor mode="on" type="Sitecore.Pipelines.Upload.Done, Sitecore.Kernel" />

</uiUpload>
```

Reference: [Customizing the Upload Process](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/sdnarchive/Articles/API/Customizing%20Upload%20Process.html)

Hope it helps!